# tesseract output is in single line instead of multiple lines

Tags: tesseract

i tried to use tesseract for ocr and the recognation is fine.

i want to recognize adresses from letter. when i read it in the following happens:

input:

`Name Name
Street
Code City`

output:
Name NameStreetCode City

i tried all -psm variaties with no effect. after googling i think -psm 4 would be the right one, but i get an error:

```
`set_count == gridheight():Error:Assert failed:in file ..\..\textord\colfind.cpp, on line 648`
```

This effect comes only on windows - on my macbook the lines are correct.
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use Unix2dos to convert the file into the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your text file in some other text processing software. In "WordPad" for example instead of regular "Notepad". Worked for me in "WordPad". :)

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract creates its output text files in UTF-8 format with Unix-style newline characters (hexadecimal 0A). Windows doesn't recognize "0A" as a new line. Windows's newline character combination is hexadecimal "0D0A". You need to substitute all "0A"s in your file with "0D0A"s. You could write a trivial program to do that, like I did, otherwise I'm sure there exist a lot of utilities for this kind of conversion.